# I hear someone say/says

Tags: verbs

Recently I stumbled upon a sentence

> I have to roll my eyes any time I hear someone say they started or
>   work for a startup.

I tried to find a grammar rule which explains it but all in vain. Can anybody point me in the right direction on why it is **"someone say"**?!

Comment: "Say" is used as an infinitive in that sentence.

Comment: I don't understand the confusion. It's the same structure as _I see someone fall down_ or _I hear a bird chirp_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I hear someone say ...
>
> Why it is "someone say"?

The subject is 'I'

The active verb is 'hear'

The object is 'someone'

The construction is similar to, 'I hear someone saying ...'

Instead we use the bare infinitive, 'I hear someone [to] say ...